# Read a compressed file *with custom extension* with spark

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I want to read gzip compressed files into a `RDD[String]` using an equivalent of `sc.textFile("path/to/file.Z")`.

Except my file extension if not `gz` but is `Z` instead, so the file is not recognised as being gzipped.

I cannot rename them as it would break production code. I do not want to copy them as they are massive and many. I guess I could use some kind of symlinks but I want to see if there is a way with scala/spark first (I am on my local windows machine for now).

How can I read this file efficiently?

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/q/39560841/877069

Comment: Also related: There is an [issue on the Spark tracker](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-29280) about adding a way to explicitly specify a compression codec when reading files, so Spark doesn't infer it from the file extension.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here there's a workaround to fix this problem http://arjon.es/2015/10/02/reading-compressed-data-with-spark-using-unknown-file-extensions/

The relevant section:

> ...extend GzipCodec and override the getDefaultExtension method.

```
package smx.ananke.spark.util.codecs

import org.apache.hadoop.io.compress.GzipCodec

class TmpGzipCodec extends GzipCodec {

  override def getDefaultExtension(): String = ".gz.tmp" // You should change it to ".Z"

}
```

> Now we just registered this codec, setting
>   spark.hadoop.io.compression.codecs on SparkConf:

```
val conf = new SparkConf()

// Custom Codec that process .gz.tmp extensions as a common Gzip format
conf.set("spark.hadoop.io.compression.codecs", "smx.ananke.spark.util.codecs.TmpGzipCodec")

val sc = new SparkContext(conf)

val data = sc.textFile("s3n://my-data-bucket/2015/09/21/13/*")
```

Comment: In case someone needs to do it in a managed service as Databricks, I've created the project to generate the lib here https://github.com/antonmry/spark-gzip-custom-extension

Comment: is there a pyspark solution to this ?

Comment: @csf found any solution?