# How does Spark SQL read compressed csv files?

Tags: csv, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I have tried with api `spark.read.csv` to read compressed csv file with extension `bz` or `gzip`. It worked. But in source code I don't find any option parameter that we can declare the `codec` type.

Even in this [link](https://github.com/databricks/spark-csv), there is only setting for `codec` in writing side. Could anyone tell me or give the path to source code that showing how spark 2.x version deal with the compressed csv file.

Comment: Note that Spark will read the compressed CSV with a single task as opposed to parallelising the read across multiple tasks when reading an uncompressed CSV.

Answer (score 4):

All text-related data sources, including [CSVDataSource](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/master/sql/core/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/sql/execution/datasources/csv/CSVDataSource.scala), use Hadoop File API to deal with files (it was in Spark Core's RDDs too).

You can find the relevant lines in [readFile](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/master/sql/core/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/sql/execution/datasources/csv/CSVDataSource.scala#L126-L137) that leads to [HadoopFileLinesReader](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/master/sql/core/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/sql/execution/datasources/HadoopFileLinesReader.scala#L38) which has the following lines:

```
val fileSplit = new FileSplit(
  new Path(new URI(file.filePath)),
  file.start,
  file.length,
  // TODO: Implement Locality
  Array.empty)
```

That uses Hadoop's [org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path](http://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r2.7.3/api/org/apache/hadoop/fs/Path.html) that deals with compression of the underlying file(s).

---

After quick googling, I was able to find the Hadoop property that deals with compression which is `mapreduce.output.fileoutputformat.compress`.

That led me to Spark SQL's [CompressionCodecs](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/master/sql/catalyst/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/sql/catalyst/util/CompressionCodecs.scala) with the following compression configuration:

```
"none" -> null,
"uncompressed" -> null,
"bzip2" -> classOf[BZip2Codec].getName,
"deflate" -> classOf[DeflateCodec].getName,
"gzip" -> classOf[GzipCodec].getName,
"lz4" -> classOf[Lz4Codec].getName,
"snappy" -> classOf[SnappyCodec].getName)
```

Below in the code, you can find [setCodecConfiguration](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/master/sql/catalyst/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/sql/catalyst/util/CompressionCodecs.scala#L61) that uses "our" option.

```
  def setCodecConfiguration(conf: Configuration, codec: String): Unit = {
    if (codec != null) {
      conf.set("mapreduce.output.fileoutputformat.compress", "true")
      conf.set("mapreduce.output.fileoutputformat.compress.type", CompressionType.BLOCK.toString)
      conf.set("mapreduce.output.fileoutputformat.compress.codec", codec)
      conf.set("mapreduce.map.output.compress", "true")
      conf.set("mapreduce.map.output.compress.codec", codec)
    } else {
      // This infers the option `compression` is set to `uncompressed` or `none`.
      conf.set("mapreduce.output.fileoutputformat.compress", "false")
      conf.set("mapreduce.map.output.compress", "false")
    }
  }
```

The other method [getCodecClassName](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/master/sql/catalyst/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/sql/catalyst/util/CompressionCodecs.scala#L42) is used to resolve `compression` option for [JSON](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/master/sql/catalyst/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/sql/catalyst/json/JSONOptions.scala#L67), [CSV](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/master/sql/core/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/sql/execution/datasources/csv/CSVOptions.scala#L116), and [text](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/master/sql/core/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/sql/execution/datasources/text/TextOptions.scala#L35) formats.

Comment: Thank you, man. I checked the `Path` package file and still get little confused. It would be very kind if you can give a little more detail; like which part of `Path` package deals with compression. THX again.

Comment: Added few additional links to Spark SQL's code where it deals with compression. Since I know nothing about Hadoop's source code, I'll leave exploring it as a home exercise for you.

Comment: Thank you so much for your patience and kindness. I read that `getCodecClassName` code through the chain. I found that part of code called only on the writing side. I didn't find usage on reading side. I thought this work might be done by filesystem; but not find the evidence.

Comment: All the pieces you reference deal with writing files. Hence why all the mentioned options have 'output' in their name. The question is about reading files.

Comment: Interesting information, but like some commenters noted it's only about the write side, not the read side. [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44374539/877069) doesn't show the relevant internals for how Spark picks a codec on read, but it does at least demonstrate how to specify a custom read codec.

Answer (score 3):

You dont have to do anything special for the `gz` compressed `csv`,`tsv` file to get read by spark `2.x` version. The below code is tried with `spark 2.0.2`

```
val options= Map("sep" -> ",")
val csvRDD = spark.read.options(options).csv("file.csv.gz")
```

I have done similarly for tab separated gz files

```
val options= Map("sep" -> "\t")
val csvRDD = spark.read.options(options).csv("file.tsv.gz")
```

Also you can specify the folder to read mulitple `.gz` file with combination of unzipped files

```
 val csvRDD = spark.read.options(options).csv("/users/mithun/tsvfilelocation/")
```