# Spark dataframe output compression(gzip) with password protected

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, spark-streaming, hadoop2

Using this below code I'm able to compress and save it as **.gz** file

```
import spark.implicits._
 

val someDF = Seq(
  (8, "bat"),
  (64, "mouse"),
  (-27, "horse")
).toDF("number", "word")

someDF.coalesce(1)
   .write.format("com.databricks.spark.csv")
    .option("header", "true")
    .option("codec", "org.apache.hadoop.io.compress.GzipCodec")
    .save("example.csv.gz")
```

**Does spark provides an option to compress data with password protected ?**  I couldn't able to find in the spark documentation.

Answer (score 3):

It is possible to create new codec that compresses the file(s) first and then encrypts them. The idea is to wrap the output streams of the codec with a [CipherOutputStream](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/crypto/CipherOutputStream.html) before writing to the file system.

```scala
import java.io.{IOException, OutputStream}

import javax.crypto.{Cipher, CipherOutputStream}
import javax.crypto.spec.SecretKeySpec
import org.apache.hadoop.io.compress._


class GzipEncryptionCodec extends GzipCodec {

  override def getDefaultExtension(): String = ".gz.enc"

  @throws[IOException]
  override def createOutputStream(out: OutputStream): CompressionOutputStream =
    super.createOutputStream(wrapWithCipherStream(out))

  @throws[IOException]
  override def createOutputStream(out: OutputStream, compressor: Compressor): CompressionOutputStream =
    super.createOutputStream(wrapWithCipherStream(out), compressor)

  def wrapWithCipherStream(out: OutputStream): OutputStream = {
    val cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/ECB/PKCS5Padding") //or another algorithm
    val secretKey = new SecretKeySpec(
      "hello world 1234".getBytes, //this is not a secure password!
      "AES")
    cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, secretKey)
    return new CipherOutputStream(out, cipher)
  }
}
```

When writing the csv file this codec can be used:

```scala
df.write
  .option("codec","GzipEncryptionCodec")
  .mode(SaveMode.Overwrite).csv("encryped_csv")
```

and the output files will be encrypted and get the suffix `.gz.enc`.

This codec only encrypts the data and cannot decrypt it. Some background on why changing the codec for reading is more difficult than for writing can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/44807144).

Instead the files can be read and decryped with a simple Scala program:

```scala
import javax.crypto.Cipher
import javax.crypto.spec.SecretKeySpec
import java.io.FileInputStream
import java.util.zip.GZIPInputStream

import javax.crypto.CipherInputStream
val cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/ECB/PKCS5Padding")
val secretKey = new SecretKeySpec("hello world 1234".getBytes(), "AES")
cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, secretKey)

val files = new File("encryped_csv").listFiles.filter(_.getName().endsWith(".gz.enc")).toList

files.foreach(f => {
  val dec = new CipherInputStream(new FileInputStream(f), cipher)
  val gz = new GZIPInputStream(dec)
  val result = scala.io.Source.fromInputStream(gz).mkString
  println(f.getName)
  println(result)
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Gzip itself doesn't support password protection.   On Unix, you need to use other tools for to encrypt the file using password.

P.S. Also, replace `com.databricks.spark.csv` with just `csv` - Spark supports CSV for a long time already. And remove corresponding Maven dependency.

Comment: any other spark codec/lib provides the capability to compress the csv with password protected?

Comment: This lib (https://github.com/srikanth-lingala/zip4j) may help I guess either I have to save all the csv files in the local and then created a zip with password protected. but i'm not sure will this work in cluster mode or not.

Comment: I'm not aware about something ready to use for CSV + something combination in Spark. I think that you may need to resort to low-level stuff, like, forEachRDD, generated CSV "manually" and write files yourself.  But it would be challenging if you aren't very deep into Spark